# How to ignore the same directory in any trees with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Hey I would like to ignore cache directories and the sub-tree of them everywhere. I tried the following:

```
syntax: glob
**/cache/**
```

It seems it is not the right thing to do. Would somebody shed some light?

Comment: should it not be just  cache/** ?

Comment: Would \*\*/cache/\*\* ignore all cache directories (and their sub-trees)? I thinking a a situation where you have multiple modules in a project, and each module has an dist, out, or build directory that you would never want checked in. I could see how this could get you into trouble (especially if you had a package named com.myapp.mymodule.util.cache or something similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to ignore everything in and below the cache folder the following should work:

```
syntax: glob
cache/**
```